# Java fx, выдает ошибку

Tags: javafx

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Судя по всему не указан путь к fxml файлу